# Why does double.TryParse() return true when the precision > 16

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, double, tryparse

With a small test I use the following code:

```
double number;
var value = "123456789.123456789";
var style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
if (Double.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
    Debug.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
```

The result is

> Converted '123456789.123456789' to 123456789.123457.

This is because `value` is too long to fit into a double. Only 16 digits are alowed. But shouldn't TryParse() return `false` since information is lost?

Comment: No because it does parse it. Just not enough bits to store the full value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Msdn [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) already underlines this fact

> However, *because of a loss of precision*, the values *may not* be equal

and it does not constitute a conversion failure, that happens instead

> **if** the s parameter is `null` or `String.Empty`, is not in a format
>   compliant with style, represents a number less than `MinValue` or
>   greater than `MaxValue`, or if style is not a valid combination of
>   `NumberStyles` enumerated constants.

Answer (score 1):

`TryParse` returns a bool value. Whether or not a value can be parsed to a double.

It does not return the exact value, only whether it can be parsed or not, as a bool.